ArchLinux - How to properly install / update system semver
Building a Kiosk software here. I do understand (perhaps too late) that ArchLinux is in an "always-evolving" state, but, so far I got a really smooth (actually amazing) experience in using it, and got a working stable version of the kiosk system I'm building. And everything is working perfectly fine - ...today.
Now I'm in the phase of finishing an update.sh script which (on the Kiosk unattended machines) does the following:

Downloads and unzips the project's (zip) repo branch (which has a packages.txt of the needed ArchLinux existent or new packages needed for that new version to operate)
Update (or install) the packages listed in that packages.txt, basically similar to the output list of pacman -Qqen > "packages.txt" just, filled manually
Delete the old application files
Copy all the new zip files to that project root and run npm install and reboot the machine

So far all fine - and works
The problem I'm facing is:
the inability to find out or understand how to "freeze" somehow a list, dep. tree, of the packages I need — and their dependency packages - after testing and making sure everything works as intended in a release stage (on a similar MiniPC as in production).
I've found a 12y old Reddit that suggests to switch to Debian - which would be a bummer. Am I at a dead-end? What approach would be best?

how to "freeze" somehow a list, dep. tree, of the packages I need Arch isn't really designed to support that. For certain packages, like the kernel packages, it is more or less fine to hold onto a version for a period of time in case that's really necessary, and you can add the names to IgnorePkg= in pacman.conf. For most packages doing so is not going to end well. (But, you mentioned npm. Are you really talking about system packages, or like nodejs packages?)

@TomYan NodeJS is irrelevant here, that's later on for the server, API and browser frontend I need. You got the question right. But than I've read about ALA (Arch Linux Archive) but unsure how to switch to it or if it's at all a good idea... :\ quite lost

ALA is just a place where you can get recent old packages individually, which are useful when some latest "edge" (of dependency tree) packages are found to have regression. It won't really help you achieve what you want.

To be frank, if you need the "security update only please; don't give me new feature" kind of update model, just don't bother sticking with Arch, as it makes no sense to contradict with yourself. (I'm saying that even when Arch has been essentially the sole distro I've been using for at least the past decade.)
